# What is the output of the Java program?

Tags: oop

What is the output of the Java program?

int a=10;

if(a==9)

System.out.println("OK ");

System.out.println("MASTER");

else

System.out.println("BYE");

Comment: What do you get when you execute ?

Answer (score 0):

It gives you error

```
$javac HelloWorld.java
HelloWorld.java:12: error: 'else' without 'if'
else
^
1 error
```

You can put braces like

```
int a=10;

if(a==9){

System.out.println("OK ");

System.out.println("MASTER");
}

else

System.out.println("BYE");
```

To get output

```
BYE
```